# wxPython MessageDialog - How to query status?

Tags: python, wxpython, status, wxwidgets, messagedialog

I'm running a wxTimer that I would like to stop, before opening a MessageDialog, and restart, when the MessageDialog has been closed.

How would I accomplish that?
I didn't find any method that would tell me whether or not the dialog has been closed or not.

At the moment the timer basically just continues ticking and more and more windows are opened at every tick :(

Hope you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: If you open the MessageDialog using `ShowModal`, then the `ShowModal` call will return when the dialog is closed.  You could set a variable (or an object attribute) to `True` just before calling `ShowModal` and `False` just afterwards, and that would give you a way of detecting whether a MessageDialog is open.

Comment: Glad it helped!  I've now written it up as a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

wxPython doesn't really have any mechanism for determining whether a MessageDialog is open.  What you can do instead is manually keep track of whether a dialog is open.

If you open the MessageDialog using `ShowModal`, then the `ShowModal` call will return when the dialog is closed.  You could use a flag which is set to `True` before the call to `ShowModal` and `False` afterwards, i.e. something like:

```
self.is_dialog_open = True
dialog.ShowModal()
self.is_dialog_open = False
```

The method called by your wx.Timer can then use `self.is_dialog_open` to determine whether the dialog is open.

Depending on how your application is structured, you might want to store this flag in some other object instead of `self`.

(I'm not making any guarantee that this code isn't prone to race conditions.  If your timer happens to check whether a dialog is open just after `ShowModal()` returns but before `self.is_dialog_open` is set back to `False`, then your timer will think that the dialog is open when it in fact has just been closed.  Hopefully this won't be a serious problem for you.)